# How to hide terms with no nodes in "Simple Hierarchical Select" in views?

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

I am using a Simple Hierarchical Select as an exposed filter in views.

How would I hide terms that have no nodes from the select box?

Answer (score 1):

There is no simple way to do that without writing custom module to eliminate the terms you wanted. That said, you can write `hook_form_alter` to achieve this.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter
 *
 **/
function MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {          
  if ($form_id == 'views_exposed_form' && $form['#id'] == 'YOUREXPOSEDFORMID') {            
    foreach ($form['field_tags_tid']['#options'] as $tid => $term_name) {
      if (is_numeric($tid)) {
        $result_count = db_select('taxonomy_index', 'ti')
        ->fields('ti')
        ->condition('ti.tid', $tid, '=')
        ->execute()
        ->rowCount();

        // Removing the option for tags with no-content
        if (!$result_count) {
          unset($form['field_tags_tid']['#options'][$tid]);
        }                
      }
    }
  }
}
```

NOTE: Here, I assumed field_tags_tid as the field name, should be replaced with the appropriate field name.

Comment: Thank you very much! I got this code to work with a regular views filter (select box). How ever I am having huge trouble getting the right field name for thge Simple Hierarchical Select. I always get error: "Notice: Undefined index.." and code doesn't work. So your code works.. maybe I should ask new question on how to get proper field name?

Comment: To be more specific.. I think I found the right filed name, but now the error is "Notice: Undefined index: #options"